# Responsive triangles with tangential vertex

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, transform

I have problem with write code which will display presented situation as in the examples below. It is about triangles, they should contact one of the vertices (
not necessarily on half the page, it would be 60/40). While the triangles are not a big problem, that responsively is a challenge for me. On the background I would like put img (maybe like background-image, maybe like diferrent layer + mask with overlay: hidden).

Model 1:
[image: model1]

Model 2:
[image: model2]

What I was tray so far:

```
<style>
.section1::after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    right: -200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 795px 750px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #fddfc0 transparent;
}
.section1 .img-right {
    position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;
}
.section2 {
    background-color: #fddfc0;
    height: 670px;
    background-image: url(../img2.png);
}

.section2 .trapezoid {
    border-bottom: 670px solid white;
    border-left: 714px solid transparent;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
</style>
<div class="section1">
    <div class="text">
        text
    </div>
    <div class="img-right"><img src="img.png" alt="" /></div>
</div>
<div class="section2">
    <div class="trapezoid">
        text
    </div>
</div>
```

As you see i tried two methods. Section1 with ::after pseudoelement which display triangle on the right and section2 where I put trapezoid on top which masks section2 div. As I said, my problem is how to make it responsive.